# What music discs are available in Single Player Survival?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[This](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Music_Discs) wiki article states two different answers in two different locations and coupled with my in game results has me completely confused.

Specifically it says in one place:

> After the 15 December 2011 snapshot (11w50a), all discs except "11" could be dropped by Creepers.

And in another place it says:

> Currently, the other nine music discs can not yet be obtained without Creative mode, SMP Server commands or external tools.

I, myself, in single player survival can only seem to get two discs; CAT and 13.
Are these the only discs avalable in SPS, or is my luck just horrible? (out of 14 successfull Skeleton vs Creeper attempts, I've still only gotten those two discs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Only Cat and 13 are available

I constructed a device for making skeletons to kill creepers in creative. I could get all music discs to be dropped.

**My test device:**

[image]

[image]

**The result (Creative):**

[image]

*However*, when I changed the game mode to Survival using NBTedit, I could only get Cat and 13 (20 trials).

**The result (Survival):**

[image]

Total creeper-related deaths: 17

Comment: Tested with the wrong version first? :P (EDIT: Never mind, saw your change was due to Creative vs. Survival, not 1.0 vs snapshots)

Comment: Intriguing...I wonder what difference creative vs. survival makes...

Answer (score 1):

The December 15 snapshot has not yet been included in any release. As such, using the current latest stable version, 1.0, only Cat and 13 are obtainable.

1.1, which will be released either today or tomorrow, will include the changes from these snapshots, and make the other discs available.

So in 1.0 and below: Only Cat and 13.
In 1.1, all discs except 11 are obtainable.